# How much can user actions be limited?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, privileges, limited-user-account

I need to use a server (Linux, Ubuntu) **'S'** as a bridge between clients and other local servers **'LSs'** which offer a series of services such as DB access via web or applications that must run on them (the other **LSs**).

Real examples:

I need clients to connect to **S** via SSH, and then they must be able tu run firefox to access **LS1** in order to manage a database via web.

I need clients to connect to **S** via SSH, and then they must be able to run on **S** Java Dsktop Apps which connect to external servers to do other things.

In short: I need clients to connect to **S** just to do what they are expected to (some of them just have to open a firefox instance, others have to be able to execute a java.jar, etc.), and hopefully they don't do anything else.

Regarding to connections I can easily use the **S** firewall to limit them to only allow connections to **LSs**, but since some of the clients like to experiment on other computers, I would like to also limit their actions beyond the simple command "$ firefox" or "$ java -jar someapp.jar".

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 as OS on servers. Obviously I can't limit accounts to "just run firefox" or "just run this .jar", but I'm interested in knowing that: How much could I limit those accounts actions?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to limit a SSH session to only a single executable. That executable can then allow for a small set of other commands to be executed, perhaps through a menu. Look at the `command` field in the `authorized_keys` file, or set the user's login shell in /etc/passwd. Note that Firefox in particular can probably be used to do quite a few things other than merely browsing to a web page.

Comment: You could also *chroot* them on **S** into a limited environment with few commands. see [an old example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot).

Comment: Thanks to both; actually @Michael Kjörling idea seems to be almost the ideal solution. I'm testing it and the only thing I haven't solved so far is avoiding users to browse local filesystem via the web-browser (They should just access a predefined domain). In fact I've taken into account your sugestion about Firefox and I'm using Midori instead.